# Are finite-domain binary constraint satisfaction problems solvable in polynomial time?

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time, constraint-satisfaction

> Suppose a CSP has $n$ variables with finite domains of maximal size $d$. Furthermore, all constraints on the variables are binary. Can such a CSP be solved in polynomial time in $n$ and $d$?

This was an exam question on last year’s AI exam, but I’m not sure how to solve it.

I know the problem of graph coloring is easily reduced to such a binary CSP, so solving them is NP-complete. Thus, I’m pretty sure that there is no known polynomial-time algorithm. Can I *prove* that there isn’t one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know, but if you manage, make sure to let us know.

The reduction seems easy indeed, with $d$ mapping to the number of colors and each constraint to an edge.

However, a polynomial-time algorithm for *any* $\mathcal{NP}$-complete problem exists if and only if $\mathcal{P} =\mathcal{NP}$; doing what you ask would imply $\mathcal{P} \neq \mathcal{NP}$.

Comment: Haha, nice — I had a feeling the question was equivalent to solving P = NP. I hope they don’t re-ask that question this year… :)